# Can two computers running Photoshop Elements 13 share the same catalog?

Tags: storage, photoshop-elements

I have a NAS which I am using to host a PSE catalog. Can this catalog be shared with another computer running PSE 13?

Comment: I meant store, there's nothing specific on the NAS relating to elements specific. Yes I'd like to know if 2 elements installs can share a catalog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is technically possible, the access times using wifi prohibited it being used as a "real" solution. I abandoned the idea in my case. If both my computers were hard wired to the my router it would have worked.

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer for PSE, but Lightroom can open catalogues from other instances of lightroom just fine, and is actually one of the methods I use when traveling with my laptop.

A quick Google - search leads to this faq for older versions of PSE, and it states that as long as you have the photos and catalogue accessible from all PC's, it's possible to have it on an external drive.

http://www.johnrellis.com/psedbtool/photoshop-elements-faq.htm#_Using_a_single

TL/DR : Lightroom can do it just fine, earlier versions of PSE can do it, and PSE 13 should also be able to.

Comment: Yes this does work, but accessing a huge catalog on a NAS can be painfully slow. I abandoned the idea for my situation which was using a computer connected via wifi to the NAS.

Comment: Hi @pfeiffep – if this answers your question, please tick the "accept answer"-box next to it. This is for the good of the community, as well as you and the answerer. If it does not answer your question, you can perhaps edit your question to include more information.